# SpringBoot 6 SecurityFilterChain migration

Tags: spring-boot

In `SpringBoot 2`, I had the following to allow `/services` and `/actuator/health`

```
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/health/**","/services/**");
  }
```

To migrate to `SpringBoot 3`, I changed it to:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(
                            "/services/**",
                            "/actuator/health")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );

    return http.build();
}
```

But the only `/actuator/health` is accessible, `/services` returns **401** error. Any idea?

It works however if I ignoring everything like below:

```
public WebSecurityCustomizer edmWebSecurityCustomizer() {
     return (web) -> web.ignoring().anyRequest();
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you calling? /services won't match the pattern. But /services/your-existing-endpoint should match.  Background: the pattern matching with the new reqquestMatchers methods is more exact then the recent antMatchers.

Comment: it is http://localhost:8080/services. It is matching the pattern if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that in spring boot 3, the way paths are recognosied have changed .For example /services and /services/ are treated differently. This could help to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi kesaven, there multiple endpoints as it is from CXF soap. I even tried hardcoding just "/services/MyWeb" but it still fails.